# Getting Undefined variable while trying to retrieve user data from database

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, pdo

I was trying to retrieve data from the "user_app" table into my table form in the view page.

Here's my **Controller**(method):

```
public function getUserApps($email) {

        $userAppsModel = new UserApps($this->pdo);

        $apps = $userAppsModel->get($email);

        return $this->view('user/dashboard', ['apps' => $apps]);
    }
```

Here's the method I used to get the data:

```
public function get($email) {
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        return $user;
    }
```

and here's my View Page (**dashboard.php**) Line 107:

```
<h1>User List</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
            
       

     **Line 107:**    <?php foreach ((array) $apps as $app) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $app['app_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $app['app_desc'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $app['app_cat'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
```

My view() method:

```php
protected function view($filename, $data = []) { 
    if (file_exists('../view/' . $filename . '.php')) { 
        require_once '../view/' . $filename . '.php';  
    }
}
```

Error Getting:
**Warning**
: Undefined variable $apps in
C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx\view\user\dashboard.php
on line
107

Comment: And which is line 107 and did you show us dashboard.php

Comment: Remember we can't see your line numbers or file names...

Comment: @RiggsFolly Line 107 start from:   **<?php foreach ((array) $apps as $app) : ?>** (referrence on the code I posted) and that is the dashboard part that needed to display the user data

Comment: @ADyson I have added the page to the post. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies, it appears that you expect `$this->view('user/dashboard', ['apps' => $apps]);` to expose an `$apps` variable to the view in `dashboard.php`. I see the codeigniter tag. I haven't used codeigniter but the docs I just looked at didn't show an OOP style (it was just a global `view()` function). I wonder if you are wrapping the codeigniter view() method & not passing the data to the codeigniter view?

Comment: @Reed Sorry for the confusion, it is a custom MVC (not codeigniter  ), and the view() method is customized to display the view page with its properties. 

Do you have the idea on how this works?

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies, in my view system I have `pubilc function view(string $view_name, array $args)`. Inside of it, I do `extract($args)`, then `require()` the view file. (*Note: [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) should be used with care, and only with trusted data*). Idk what your custom MVC is doing though.

Inside your view file, you could do two things to help with debugging. 1. `print_r(get_defined_vars())` and `debug_print_backtrace()`. The first will let you see what vars are present. The backtrace can help you track down any code that's not right.

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies my guess would be that your MVC is not `extract()`ing the passed in array, or if it is doing an `extract`, then that the `include`/`require` is not in the same scope.

Comment: @Reed, thanks. Here's my View function:

**protected function view($filename, $data = []) {

  if (file_exists('../view/' . $filename . '.php')) {
            
   require_once '../view/' . $filename . '.php';
  }
 }**

How can I use extract with it?

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies, I edited your question to include the `view()` code. And I added an answer. Hope that gets you where you need. I threw in some unsolicited suggestions while I was at it, which you should feel free to ignore.

Comment: @Reed Thank you, it works. 
Actually I am just getting into PHP OOP (MVC). 

I am having some other issue I think it is issue: 

On my UserDashboard controller, data's passed from other functions like profile() are not showing on dashboard when I pass it. something like:  **public function profile() {

        $name = [

            'name' => 'ola',
            'color'=> 'primary'
        ];

        return $this->view('user/dashboard', compact('name'));
    }**.

Comment: @Reed, then tried to output on user/dashboard view page: 
  **<?php if(isset($name)): ?>
        
            <?php $name = $data['name']; 
            
            echo $name['name']; 
            echo $name['color'] 
            
            ?>
        
            <?php else: ?>
            <p>No name found.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>**. Am i the one missing something or that's the rule?

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies In `profile()`, you're declaring the `$name` variable, then calling view with `compact('name')` & not passing the `$name` variable. In `user/dashboard`, you're checking `isset($name)` just BEFORE you set `$name = ...`. I think you'd want to check `if (isset($data['name']))` rather than `isset($name)`. Idk what `compact('name')` is supposed to do, but I think you'd want to pass `['name'=>$name]` instead.

Comment: @KwiksellerTechnologies, unrelated StackOverflow tip: Surround `code` in backticks (probably upper left of your keyboard, to the left of #1) instead of **bolding** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `view()` method is not `extract()`ing the `$data` argument, so `$data['apps']` is not being made available to your view.

Prior to `require`ing your view file, you need to use `extract($data)`.

**NOTE:** `extract()` is a dangerous method and should NEVER be used with untrusted data (such as from `$_GET` or `$_POST`), because `extract` makes array keys available as variables.

**Solution:**
Here is a rewritten version of your `view()` method using extract:

```php
protected function view($filename, $data = []) { 
    if (file_exists('../view/' . $filename . '.php')) { 
        extract($data); // $data['apps'] is now exposed as $apps variable
        require_once '../view/' . $filename . '.php';
    }
}
```

THOUGH, your use of `require_once` could cause you problems. If a view is to be displayed twice on the same request, only the first call to `view()` will do anything. I'd replace `require_once` with `require`

**Unrelated Suggestion:**
I'm personally fond of early returns, instead of nesting meaningful code inside if blocks. I also like explicit pathing and types. You can ignore this suggestion, but I personally would write the method more like this:

```php
protected function view(string $filename, array $data = []) { 
    $file_path = __DIR__.'/../view/'.$filename.'.php';
    if (!file_exists($file_path))return;
    
    extract($data); // expose each array key as a variable.
    require $file_path;
}
```